# The abscissa of convergence of the real part of a Dirichlet series

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Let $L(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{a(n)}{n^s}$ be a Dirichlet series with a finite abscissa of convergence $\sigma_c.$ My question is the following :

On what condition the abscissa of convergence of  $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{\mathrm{Re}(a(n))}{n^s}$ is equal to $\sigma_c$ ?
The same question for $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{\mathrm{Im}(a(n))}{n^s}$.

Comment: It's all the same.  A sequence of complex numbers converges if and only if the sequence of real parts converges and the sequence of imaginary parts converges.  Since the abscissa of convergence of a Dirichlet series is determined where it converges for real $s$, take $s$ real and then your two sums are the real and imaginary parts of $L(s)$.

Comment: Unfortunately @KConrad's comment isn't correct. That argument does show that the abscissas of convergence of the real and imaginary parts are at most as large as the abscissa of convergence of $L$, and also (I think) that one of them must be equal to the original abscissa. But the other one can be much smaller. The Riemann zeta function is an example—its "imaginary part" version is identically zero and thus has abscissa of convergence $-\infty$.

Comment: @GregMartin, right you are. What I wrote above is correct except for the first sentence. I should have said the abscissa of convergence for $L(s)$ equals the maximum of the abscissas of convergence for the two series with real part and imaginary part coefficients since for real $s$ we have $s > \sigma_L$ if and only if $s > \sigma_{{\rm Re} L}$ and $s > \sigma_{{\rm Im} L}$.

Answer (score 3):

See [what's on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence) $\sigma = \underset{N \to \infty}{\lim \sup} \frac{\ln |L-\sum_{n = 1}^N a_n |}{\ln N}$
and hence $$\sigma_{Re} = \underset{N \to \infty}{\lim \sup} \frac{\ln |Re(L)-\sum_{n = 1}^N Re(a_n )|}{\ln N} \le\underset{N \to \infty}{\lim \sup} \frac{\ln |L-\sum_{n = 1}^N a_n |}{\ln N} = \sigma$$

That's all we can say, see Greg's comment.